# Algorithm: How to use x and y mouse movement co-ordinates to generate random data?

Tags: random-number-generator, one-time-pad, randomness, entropy

**Background:**

I'm making a program for fun as a learning exercise. I want to generate some *actual random* key material (not pseudorandom) from a JavaScript program. For my program is just for encrypting/decrypting plain text letter by letter so I've chosen to use the [ASCII printable character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) (what characters you can type on a standard US keyboard) which gives 95 possible characters.

I want to capture a users' random mouse movements on screen to capture a long stream of random numbers. I want to use the x & y coordinates from each mouse position out of a possible screen resolution of 1920x1080 pixels and then map them back to a character within the list of possible ASCII characters. Then I can use that character in my key material. Let's say the program captures the following series of x and y coordinates like so:

```
[478,702]    
[503,701]    
[581,687]    
[633,670]    
[691,646]    
[757,620]    
[814,599]
```

**Question 1:**

At this point should I multiply the x and y coordinates to get a better random number, ie `478 x 702 = 335556` and use this number? Because if I just took the x number separately then you might end up with consecutive numbers e.g. `121, 122, 123, 127` as they're moving the mouse in one direction which doesn't look particularly random. Or should I add the numbers together ie `478 + 702 = 1180`? Or perhaps alternate between adding and multiplying for each set of coordinates I get to make the random number?

**Question 2:**

Now what's the best way to map the random number to a character in my list (array) of possible characters? If I've got an array of all the 95 characters `[0 - 94]` for a zero based array, and lets say my random number is 1180, how do I map that back to a character in my array? Do I loop over the array multiple times until I'm at the 1180th character and now use that character for my key? Essentially this would be like repeating the 95 possible characters in a row up to 1180 characters, then taking the last one. Or maybe you can work this out mathematically?

Or do I create a big 2D array with all the characters repeated horizontally and vertically (like a big grid to match the screen size), then when an x and y mouse coordinate comes in I map it to the x and y indexes in the big 2D array and use that character?

**Question 3:**

What is the entropy quality of the random numbers generated from the mouse movements? Does mapping it back to the reduced character set reduce the entropy? How can you make the process of capturing random data from the mouse movements better?

**Question 4:**

If my screen size is 1920x1080 pixels and I pull out an x and y coordinate from that. What is the search space ie $2^x$? how do you work that out?

Many thanks

Comment: stuff them all into a crypto hash such as SHA-512.

Comment: Q1: Multiplying not-very-random numbers together won't result in numbers being any more random.  

Q2: Check out [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), the modulo operator in many languages is expressed with a '%' symbol.  Ie, 1180 % 95 = 40 (where 1180 is the random number, there are 95 characters, and 40 is the resulting character).

Comment: Great, thanks @hunter. I guess I was trying to say that just taking the X coordinates by themselves isn't particularly random as they could be moving the mouse in one direction (typical use) so you'd get a string of increasing numbers e.g. 123 124 127 129 etc but combining it with the Y coordinates as well you get a more unique number, no? If so what would be the correct way to combine the two numbers for maximum randomness?

Comment: @CodesInChaos, why put them all into a crypto hash?

Comment: @zuallauz Cryptographic hash functions take data which isn't necessarily uniformly distributed (not the case here, as you've observed) but still contain entropy, and convert them into a uniformly distributed bitstring with entropy approximately equal to the input (up to the hash function's output size). So it'll take those mouse coordinates and process them into a form fit for use as cryptographic key material (careful not to overestimate entropy)

Comment: In general: rolling your own RNG for cryptographic purpose is hard (especially determining that you have enough input), and you should not attempt it for real with you current knowledge. Hint on Q1: consider what happens for the two different inputs [200,330] and [300,220], when you use, on one hand: hash of the whole input, and on the other hand; hash of the product of the two numbers in the input.

Comment: That's a good point @fgrieu thanks. So hashing "200330" and "300220" will produce a different hash.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Thomas. Let's say I did hash of the x (200) and y (333) values concatenated together (200330) with the SHA512 algorithm. That would produce a 128 characters (128 byte string). Can I use each character of that string as key material? Especially if I am using each character to encrypt a single plain text character (similar to OTP)?

Comment: Hashing "200330" and "300220" will (very likely) produce different output. However consider what happens for input [20,111] and input [201,11]. More generally, to **best** use the entropy in the input, it should be formatted in a _reversible_ manner into the message fed to the hash; e.g. if you start from pairs on numbers in decimal coded as ASCII, hash messages like `[30,222][302,22]` or `30:222;302:22;`. These are theoretical nitpicks with little practical consequence. Many other things (like deciding when there's enough input) matter very much in practice.

Comment: @fgrieu, are you saying hash the x and y along with the brackets/colons so there is a distinction in the resulting hashes?  What about concatenating the x and y, then multiplying that by x and then dividing that by the y? So that fixes the [200,330] and [300,220] problem (result 121412.1, 409390.9) and also the [20, 111] and [201,11] problem too (result 4084.054, 414865.64). Might run into divide by 0 errors/negative numbers though if the mouse pointer is near [0, 0]...

Comment: Yes, hashing the x and y along with the brackets/colons insure that no entropy is lost. I think it is possible to exhibit colliding pairs with your new ad-hoc scheme (at least I'm sure proving the contrary is hard); in crypto, we like schemes with a simple proof!

Comment: You'll want to have a look at random.js from the Stanford JS Crypto Library. E.g., [this function](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/master/core/random.js#L366) is registered to handle mouse movements. Appears to be based on [Fortuna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_(PRNG))

Comment: @fgrieu Does hashing the commas/brackets reduce entropy? Let's say I joined up 8 separate sets of coordinates, then there would be a lot of commas and brackets in that string too which aren't random. Does that matter? Also if I am hashing just a small string (the [200,330]) then hashing that, then I use that hash for my OTP key, is it theoretically possible that someone could create a rainbow table of all the possible combinations of the x,y values, then they'd have all my possible keys. Then they could get the encrypted text and try out all the keys to see if it matched?

Comment: @fgrieu Potentially what I think we need to do is capture x,y coordinates until we have 128 bytes of unique entropy then hash it with SHA2/SHA3 hash. What do you think?

Comment: @zuallauz: Adding commas/brackets do not decrease the entropy; it avoids losing entropy; but reduces the entropy per hashed character. If your input does not contain enough entropy (including, **but not limited to**, because is is short), yes the hash's output can be guessed by enumerating the possible inputs (not with a rainbow table). A comment can't answer your question, but one hard part is checking how much entropy there is in the input, and ascertaining there is any (e.g. a mouse location may vibrate by 1 pixel due power supply ripple; is mouse location secret?). See D.W.'s advice.

Comment: @fgrieu: You say it reduces the entropy per hashed character, but by how much? Do you think I should throw all the gathered entropy into a pool, combine with some other entropy (e.g. keyboard, mouse clicks, milliseconds between mouse clicks) then when I've gathered enough entropy equal to the hash bit length e.g. 256bit, then hash that string, and that can be the key?

Answer (score 9):

The [PuTTYgen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) program, which is open source, contains the following comment in [WINPGEN.C](https://github.com/grumpydev/PortablePuTTY/blob/master/WINDOWS/WINPGEN.C) where it collects mouse movement for key generation:

```
/*
* My brief statistical tests on mouse movements
* suggest that there are about 2.5 bits of
* randomness in the x position, 2.5 in the y
* position, and 1.7 in the message time, making
* 5.7 bits of unpredictability per mouse movement.
* However, other people have told me it's far less
* than that, so I'm going to be stupidly cautious
* and knock that down to a nice round 2. With this
* method, we require two words per mouse movement,
* so with 2 bits per mouse movement we expect 2
* bits every 2 words.
*/
```

I don't know how accurate this information is. I just remembered seeing it and though it was worth sharing.

Comment: It may even be lesser than that, considering users usually draw circles or do zig-zag-zig-zag-zig-zag.

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to microphone these papers describe a method to generate true random number.

> Nur Azman Abu and Zulkiflee Muslim, Random Number Generation for
>   Cryptographic Key, Proceedings International Conference on Engineering
>   and ICT, ICEI 2007, 27–28 November 2007, Melaka, Malaysia, Volume 1,
>   pp 255–260.
>
> Nur Azman Abu and Zulkiflee Muslim, Random Room Noise for
>   Cryptographic Key, Proceedings IEEE International Conference on
>   Digital Ecosystem and Technologies DEST2008, 27–29 February 2008,
>   Phitsanulok, Thailand, pp381–387.

and [this thesis](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/theses/cotter.pdf) proposed a method to generate pseudo random numbers from microphone input in computing devices.

Answer (score 4):

For your questions 1 and 3, you want to know how to convert mouse movements into usable random numbers.  Others have made good suggestions there.  If the PuTTYGen comments are to be believed, one movement could contribute as much as 2 bits of uncertainty. As you have stated that this project is for fun, this seems like a good place to do an experiment of your own.  Multiplication, however, is likely not an effective way to combine the bits to make them particularly random.  Instead, I would concatenate the mouse bytes and once I gathered enough data that contained 256 bits of uncertainty, (128 mouse readings, if the 2 bits-per-mouse-movement figure is to be trusted) I would run the concatenated data into a SHA-256 hash algorithm, and the resultant digest value would be my string of random bytes.

I don't personally believe that mouse movements should be the only source of randomness, so I would be mixing in other information as well, but that's not what you asked.

For question 2, it looks like you're trying to use the random data as a one-time pad (OTP), also known as a Vernam cypher, to encrypt some ASCII bytes.  The pre-computer way of doing this was to use a random number from 0-25 and shift the character by that many places.  In the computer world, we normally use a byte-for-byte XOR operation, where one byte of plaintext is XORed with one byte of random data.

Comment: OK sure I could include some other entropy sources later into the entropy pool, mouse clicks, time between mouse clicks, keyboard and hardware entropy. Let's say my program returns X and Y mouse coordinates 478,702. This is out of a usable screen space of 1920×1080 screen size. So you're saying concatenate them, then that would become 478,702 but if I run that through an ASCII to binary converter I actually get 7 bytes 0110100 0110111 0111000 0101100 0110111 0110000 0110010.

Comment: fgrieu above says to keep the comma in to separate the numbers because you might get two different coordinates 20,111 and 201,11 but they would be the same number 20111 when concatenated together. Putting the comma in keeps them separated and will result in a different hash.

Comment: My questions then would be, how does the mouse x and y only produce 2 bits of randomness per mouse movement? Also if I was joining the numbers together in a big string to consolidate 128 mouse readings before hashing, does having that many commas in the string reduce the entropy?

Comment: The reason a mouse movement has very little entropy is that there is very little randomness going into it. If your hand is moving mostly left, you will generate 50 pairs of numbers that vary predictably in a sequence: 478,702  477,702  476,702 475,703, 474,703 473,703  etc.  The entropy (unpredictability) comes primarily from changes in direction, which certainly don't happen with every mouse reading. ASCII or binary has nothing to do with it - it's simply not very random.

Comment: Furthermore, you have to understand that ASCII and binary are simply different readable ways for humans to understand the value.  7 apples means 7 apples, regardless if I write it in text "seven apples", decimal "7 apples", or binary "0111 apples".  Inside the computer, the mouse value of 478 is stored in a two-byte or four-byte integer.  Simply take those two or four bytes, and place them in a buffer.  Take another mouse reading, and place them next to the first bytes. Repeat until you have placed as many mouse readings as you have determined the amount of entropy in a mouse reading to be -

Comment: - times the number of bits of your hash algorithm.  If you determine it takes four mouse readings to get a single bit of entropy, and each mouse reading is stored in two(2) four-byte integers, then you would need 1024 mouse readings making up a total buffer of 8192 bytes to run through a SHA-256 hash.  This would produce 256 bits (32 bytes), of presumably random values.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9246/discussion-between-john-deters-and-zuallauz)

Answer (score 4):

All of the responses so far have answered your question, but it is interesting to note that this method of collecting random mouse movements has been implemented before by a commercial Certification Authority. I speak from first hand experience of using this, because I worked for the company the created it. Baltimore Technologies (now Verizon Enterprise Services) own the UniCERT Certification Authority Suite. This features the seeding of the [Blum-Blum-Shub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub) RNG using the collection of random key presses and mouse movements. This, in turn, was used to generate random numbers for RSA keys generated in software.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to generate random key material, I suggest a simpler solution: use the OS support for generating entropy.  On Linux, read from `/dev/urandom`.  On Windows, use `CryptGenRandom`.  Search to find support on other platforms.

If you're doing this in Javascript, read the following:

- [Compatibility of window.crypto.getRandomValues()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16084766/781723)
- [Generate cryptographically strong pseudorandom numbers in Javascript?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/20029/971)

Those questions fully cover the topic for Javascript.  In general, your best bet is probably going to be to use `window.crypto.getRandomValues()` on browsers that support it, and fall back to something else (server-generated random numbers delivered to the client over SSL, or an existing library, such as the Stanford Javascript Crypto Library).

Comment: The language I am doing this in does not have access to the raw operating system's PSRNG streams. Also I need actual random not psuedo random.

Comment: @zuallauz, *"language... does not have access"* - Are you sure?  What language and platform are you using?  (Those primitives are generally available to all user-level programs; you don't need root or administrator permissions to access them.)

Comment: @zuallauz, *"I need actual random not psuedo random"* - I very much doubt this.  The entropy sources I listed are designed to be cryptographic-strength: i.e., adequate for generating cryptographic keys.  (Moreover, the kind of approach you were sketching in your question *also* generates pseudorandom numbers, not true random ones, so if pseudorandom is insufficient for some unlikely reason, the approach you were sketching is insufficient too.  But realistically I think you've misinterpreted the requirements for generating cryptographic keys.)

Comment: I'm using a client side language JavaScript for a program similar to a one-time pad. From my research it mentions `/dev/random` should be suitable for uses that need very high quality randomness such as OTP or key generation. From experience though it outputs random data very slowly ie 1 byte per 30 seconds. `/dev/urandom` contains less entropy and is intended as a pseudorandom number generator suitable for most cryptographic purposes but it is not recommended for the generation of long-term cryptographic keys or OTPs. None of the OS entropy sources are available to JavaScript unfortunately.

Comment: @zuallauz, Ahh, I see, Javascript!  Right.  For Javascript, see my edited answer.  (This would have been a good requirement to list in the original question.)  For `/dev/random` vs `/dev/urandom`, you've been misled by a poorly written man page: that's a very common misconception, but it's still wrong.  See http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3936/971 and http://security.stackexchange.com/a/14314/971

Comment: Thanks, the [WebCryptoAPI](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) you linked to looks interesting however there's no guarantee that the algorithm and entropy source the browser is using to generate the 'cryptographically secure random' bytes is actually random. In the spec it says they can only guarantee it to be psuedo-random, so not good for a OTP. Maybe you could feed bits of it into the random pool and combine it with a few other methods.

Comment: For your edited answer you also mention falling back to server-generated random numbers delivered to the client over SSL. That sounds terrible as then you're sending your random numbers for your one-time pad key over a less secure transmission medium. The security of the one-time pad that used those random numbers would then only be as secure as the SSL used. So if the SSL was broken/intercepted/hijacked they could grab the random numbers and later decrypt your one-time pad. The generation of the random numbers must be done in JavaScript and stay client side as if it was a regular C++ program.

Comment: @zuallauz, I see many misconceptions here.  Again, as I stated before, what you are calling "pseudorandom" is perfectly fine for this purpose.  Also, if SSL is broken, you have far bigger problems: other attacks become possible.  The OTP is a poor choice for practical security.  Finally, if you need very high-assurance security, for heaven's sakes, don't use Javascript and the web to implement it!

Comment: Not too worried about the practicality of the OTP, leave that for me to worry about. As far as programming is concerned it is actually the most practical to develop. Rather than something like RSA which requires a PhD in maths to understand all the notation etc.

Answer (score 3):

**Part 1**

There are some methods to do it.

- [Phrack magazine](http://www.phrack.com/issues.html?issue=59&id=15)

Get the last four bits from `x`, the last four from `y`, concatenate them, `XOR` them with the last 8 bits that you get from your system timer (or from the fastest timer you have available)

- are you using [java?](http://tech.cryptzone.com/Mindterm_API_Documentation/com/mindbright/util/RandomSeed.html)

you can specify mouse movements to be a source of entropy

- what I would do:

Get your mouse position X, Y (last 4 bits of each), time it was collected (last 4 bits of each), concatenate everything.

Have a pool of random bytes. When a new random number is requested, get the last number, XOR it with the concatenation above, hash it with some hash (like SHA-1, SHA-2, MD5), use the last `x` bits, update the random pool with this number.

- also take a look at [this analysis on how linux pseudo-random number generator](http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/086.pdf) works.

**Part 2**

And just to add up: it's not because you're using the mouse inputs that you'll have real random number. The numbers got from OS, etc, are called pseudo-random because if you give them the same inputs again, it'll generate the same random number.

If you use mouse moviments, the same thing will happen: you'll have a number that could be generated again, if someone moved it in the same way, etc.

Real random numbers are hard to get. Some devices use quantum effects to get it, for example. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator) is your friend here.

Comment: downvoter, would you mind to comment / improve my answer and help me (and others) have a better understading?

Comment: I didn't downvote! I'm still processing this answer. Lets say I have X and Y coordinates of 478,702 out of a usable screen space of 1920×1080 pixels. Converting these numbers to binary gives me 001101000011011100111000 for 478 and 001101110011000000110010 for 702, which is 24bits long. In the phrack article I'm only seeing numbers with 16bits of binary code. I think he did his testing in a small portion of the screen ie 99x99 pixels? The largest number I might have is 1920 00110001001110010011001000110000 which is 32bits. Are you saying I can't use all of that and only the last 4 bits?

Comment: the idea from the article is that when you make small movements with your mouse (let's say move from 400 to 403), the leftmost bits won't change, but the last four ones will... See how 478, 702 and 1920 all begin with 00110... why bother using those bits, that are constant? That's the idea of the article. :-) I didn't say you downvoted it, just someone did and I was curious why...

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://www.merrymeet.com/jon/usingrandom.html) is a very detailed description about creating random numbers and how to "distill" randomness from various sources into a single number. It is an older article, but it has its truths.

A good way to get a single random number from various sources is concatenation-then-hash. Since you're doing this for fun, you don't really NEED to consider the minimum entropy of mouse movement, but you should not use the entire number itself. Let's say we want to have 6 bit from each coordinate. Then we calculate 
$$
r = x \text{ mod } 2^{6}\\
s = y \text{ mod } 2^{6}
$$
This gives you a fairly even distribution of $(r,s)$ even if you move the mouse only in a certain part of the screen. For an exact analysis of YOUR mouse, you need to do some statistical tests (e.g. if your mouse produces only even numbers, this doesn't work properly). You also might want to make sure, that you throw away x and y, if they are the same as the previous position (no movement). Once you collected enough pair $(r_i,s_i)$ you can just concatenate them and use a decent cryptographic hash function (e.g. SHA-256). If you want to use the entire hash output for random symbols, you should put at least 22 pairs $r_i,s_i$ (assuming 12 bit of entropy each) together, to match the resulting 256 bit output.

From the output $h$ of the hash function you can either go various ways:

- Pick 7 bits from the output and interpret as characters. Throw away numbers beyond your character set (otherwise you get an uneven distribution).
- Arithmetic calculation: Use  $(h \text{ mod } 95)$ for your first character and then set $(h = h / 95)$. Then use $(h \text{ mod } 95)$ is your next char, etc.
- Seed a cryptographically pseudo random number generator with $h$ and extract numbers from the resulting stream. You can do fancy constructions like seed a PRNG with $h$, take a number of bits for characters and then take a number of bits, XOR them with the next hash value and use this as a new seed for the PRNG.

Answer (score 2):

[This paper](http://hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-135.pdf) gives (starting on page 3) a representation (described in the last paragraph of page 1)

of [irreducible polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial) over the [binary field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF%282%29), and will suffice for generating the seed from

sources that are less than 10000 bits long. $\:$ [This paper](http://ams.org/mcom/1990-54-189/.../S0025-5718-1990-0993933-0.pdf) gives a deterministic and provably efficient

algorithm to find such polynomials, and can be used for sources that might be 10000 bits or longer.

Let $\;\; \mathbf{c} \: = \: c_0\hspace{.02 in}c_1\hspace{.02 in}c_2\hspace{.02 in}...\hspace{.02 in}c_{L-1} \;\;$ be a bitstring such that

$c_0 \cdot x^0 \: + \: c_1 \cdot x^1 \: + \: c_2 \cdot x^2 \: + \: ... \: + \: c_{L-1} \cdot x^{L-1} \: + \: x^L$

is an irreducible polynomial over the binary field, as described above.

Define $\;\; \operatorname{mbx} : \{0,\hspace{-0.02 in}1\}^L \to \{0,\hspace{-0.02 in}1\}^L \;\;$ by $\;\; \operatorname{mbx}\left(b_0\hspace{.02 in}b_1\hspace{.02 in}b_2\hspace{.02 in}...\hspace{.02 in}b_{L-2}\hspace{.02 in}0\right) \: = \: 0\hspace{.03 in}b_0\hspace{.02 in}b_1\hspace{.02 in}b_2\hspace{.02 in}...\hspace{.02 in}b_{L-2}$

and $\;\;\;\;\;\; \operatorname{mbx}\left(b_0\hspace{.02 in}b_1\hspace{.02 in}b_2\hspace{.02 in}...\hspace{.02 in}b_{L-2}\hspace{.02 in}1\right) \;\;\; = \;\;\; 0\hspace{.03 in}b_0\hspace{.02 in}b_1\hspace{.02 in}b_2\hspace{.02 in}...\hspace{.02 in}b_{L-2} \:\: \text{xor} \:\: c_0\hspace{.02 in}c_1\hspace{.02 in}c_2\hspace{.02 in}...\hspace{.02 in}c_{L-1} \;\;\;\;\;\;$.

Define $\;\; \operatorname{mbx}^0 : \{0,\hspace{-0.02 in}1\}^L \to \{0,\hspace{-0.02 in}1\}^L \;\;$ by $\;\; \operatorname{mbx}\left(b_0\hspace{.02 in}b_1\hspace{.02 in}b_2\hspace{.02 in}...\hspace{.02 in}b_{L-1}\right) \: = \: b_0\hspace{.02 in}b_1\hspace{.02 in}b_2\hspace{.02 in}...\hspace{.02 in}b_{L-1} \;\;$.

For all non-negative integers $n$, define $\;\; \operatorname{mbx}^{\hspace{.01 in}n+1} : \{0,\hspace{-0.02 in}1\}^L \to \{0,\hspace{-0.02 in}1\}^L \;\;$ by

$\operatorname{mbx}^{\hspace{.01 in}n+1}\hspace{-0.01 in}\left(b_0\hspace{.02 in}b_1\hspace{.02 in}b_2\hspace{.02 in}...\hspace{.02 in}b_{L-1}\right) \: = \: \operatorname{mbx}^n\hspace{-0.01 in}\left(\operatorname{mbx}\left(b_0\hspace{.02 in}b_1\hspace{.02 in}b_2\hspace{.02 in}...\hspace{.02 in}b_{L-1}\right)\right) \;\;\;$.

For bitstrings $\;\; \mathbf{a} \: = \: a_0\hspace{.02 in}a_1\hspace{.02 in}a_2\hspace{.02 in}...\hspace{.02 in}a_{L-1} \;\;$ and $\;\; \mathbf{b} \: = \: b_0\hspace{.02 in}b_1\hspace{.02 in}b_2\hspace{.02 in}...\hspace{.02 in}b_{L-1} \;\;$,

let $\:\langle \mathbf{a},\hspace{-0.02 in}\mathbf{b}\rangle\:$ denote $\;\;\;\; a_0 \hspace{.02 in}\text{&}\hspace{.03 in} b_0 \;\; \text{xor} \;\; a_1 \hspace{.02 in}\text{&}\hspace{.03 in} b_1 \;\; \text{xor} \;\; a_2 \hspace{.02 in}\text{&}\hspace{.03 in} b_2 \;\; \text{xor} \;\; a_{L-1} \hspace{.02 in}\text{&}\hspace{.03 in} b_{L-1} \;\;\;\;$.

For all members $s$ of $\{0,\hspace{-0.03 in}1,\hspace{-0.03 in}2,...,\hspace{-0.03 in}L\}$, $\:$ define $\;\; \operatorname{BLE}_{\mathbf{c}}^s \: : \: \{0,\hspace{-0.02 in}1\}^L \hspace{-0.01 in} \times \{0,\hspace{-0.02 in}1\}^L \: \to \: \{0,\hspace{-0.02 in}1\}^s \;\;$ by

$\operatorname{BLE}_{\mathbf{c}}^s(\mathbf{a},\hspace{-0.03 in}\mathbf{b}) \;\; = \;\; \left\langle \hspace{-0.03 in}\operatorname{mbx}^0\hspace{-0.02 in}(\mathbf{a}),\hspace{-0.02 in}\mathbf{b}\hspace{-0.04 in} \right\rangle \: \left\langle \hspace{-0.03 in}\operatorname{mbx}^1\hspace{-0.02 in}(\mathbf{a}),\hspace{-0.02 in}\mathbf{b}\hspace{-0.04 in} \right\rangle \: \left\langle \hspace{-0.03 in}\operatorname{mbx}^2\hspace{-0.02 in}(\mathbf{a}),\hspace{-0.02 in}\mathbf{b}\hspace{-0.04 in} \right\rangle \: ... \: \left\langle \hspace{-0.03 in}\operatorname{mbx}^{\hspace{.01 in}s-1}\hspace{-0.02 in}(\mathbf{a}),\hspace{-0.02 in}\mathbf{b}\hspace{-0.04 in} \right\rangle \;\;\;$.

When the user first receives the program, the user generates $\:\mathbf{a} \in \{0,\hspace{-0.02 in}1\}^L\:$,$\:$ then evaluates

and stores $\:\left[\hspace{-0.01 in}\operatorname{mbx}^2\hspace{-0.02 in}(\mathbf{a}),\operatorname{mbx}^2\hspace{-0.02 in}(\mathbf{a}),\operatorname{mbx}^2\hspace{-0.02 in}(\mathbf{a}),...,\operatorname{mbx}^2\hspace{-0.02 in}(\mathbf{a})\hspace{-0.01 in}\right]\:$. $\;\;$ The recursion makes that

computation faster than it would otherwise be, and $\mathbf{a}$ does *not* need to be kept secret.

To generate random data, the user generates $\:\mathbf{b} \in \{0,\hspace{-0.02 in}1\}^L$

and then outputs $\: \operatorname{BLE}_{\mathbf{c}}^s(\mathbf{a},\hspace{-0.03 in}\mathbf{b}) \:$ as the random data.

For random variables $Z$, let $\:||Z||\:$ denote $\;\; \mathop{\operatorname{max}}_z \: \operatorname{Prob}(Z = z) \;\;$.

(So, $\:||Z||\:$ being small corresponds to $Z$ having high min-entropy.)

For all random variables $X$ and $Y$ taking values on $\{0,\hspace{-0.02 in}1\}^L$, if $\: ||X|| \leq \frac1{2^{b_x}} \:$ and $\: ||Y|| \leq \frac1{2^{b_y}}$

and $X$ is independent of $Y$ **then** for $U$ uniform on $\{0,\hspace{-0.02 in}1\}^L$ and independent of $Y$,

for all functions $\;\; \mathcal{D} \: : \: \{0,\hspace{-0.02 in}1\}^L \hspace{-0.01 in} \times \{0,\hspace{-0.02 in}1\}^s \: \to \: \{0,\hspace{-0.02 in}1\} \;\;$,

$\left|\operatorname{Prob}\left(\mathcal{D}\left(Y,\operatorname{BLE}_{\mathbf{c}}^s(Y,X)\right) = 1\right)-\operatorname{Prob}(\mathcal{D}(Y,U) = 1)\right| \;\; \leq \;\; 2^\left(-\left(b_x+b_y+2-(L+s)\right)\right) \;\;\;$.

Comment: As far as I know those theoretical constructions have no known practical advantages over simply hashing it all using a cryptographic hash function.

Comment: Thanks, but not sure I have enough maths knowledge to understand all the notation in the first PDF. Can you summarise it in layman's terms for me what I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use PBKF2 key generation function. Use some integer generated by the mouse movement as the input. PBKF2 function will give you a random output with more entropy than the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xinput --test` to record mouse movement data and then "crunch" the recorded data into a random hash using a hash algorithm like MD5.

E.g. `xinput --list` (shows your mouse device id is 15) and you want to collect
5 seconds of mouse data:

`$> mouse_data=$(timeout 5 xinput --test 15)`

If you want to play around with a script that incorporates this already: 
https://code.google.com/p/gen-uniq-id/source/browse/gen_uniq_id.bsh

I just finished writing it, it is a fairly robust Bash script that incorporates /dev/urandom, mouse movements, current time and dynamic text into a random md5sum. You can turn some features on/off and modify the length of data collection time via user options.

```
 ## To generate a random md5sum based on random data collected
 ## over 0.004353 seconds without any collected mouse movement data, 
 ## set text block to "my favorite quote" 
 $ gen_uniq_id.bsh -r".000004353354e+03" -m0 -s"my favorite quote"

 ## To turn off random collection and set mouse collection to 1.5 
 ## seconds, and seed with the last 5 commands from history w/debug on 
 ## to see the internal variables
 $ gen_uniq_id.bsh -d -m1.5 -r0 -s$(history|tail -5) 2>&1 | more
```

As far as your questions regarding the exergy of mouse movement data, it really depends on the user, if you are going to be rather predictable and slide the mouse up a little when the mouse movement data is being collected you're going to be much more predictable than if you zig-zag like a madman.

The good news is that it shouldn't really matter that much as long as you get some decent random seed, from there it is the strength of the pseudo-random generator. I use my script all the time yet tend to get a bit lazy about moving my mouse when its generating so I made it possible to seed additionally with the history data of my shell. Its not really random but when you combine that in a string with time down to the nanosecond, a little bit of /dev/urandom and some mouse movements you get a fairly decent seed to crunch into a MD5 sum.

Answer (score 0):

Actually mouse movements are used in some software and projects to create behavioral fingerprints of users (eg people move their mouses in unique ways ) , so needless to say they are no a very good source of randomness , considering a single person , they contain informations that allow to characterize a user ( with some FAR/FRR of course ).